# Thread blocking sometimes while unzipping png files

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android app that requires downloading a zip file (around 1,5 MB max) with a small amount of logos (png files of 20-30KB average size) from  a webserver.

I have encapsulated the process of downloading and unzipping the files into android internal storage in an `AsyncTask`'s `doInbackground()` method.
The issue I have is that the `unZipIntoInternalStorage()` method I have developed (pasted down), **sometimes** runs forever. Usually it takes around 900ms  seconds to unzip and save the logos into internal storage, but for some unknown reason around 1 of 4 executions blocks during the loop (and stays there "for ever" taking more than 2 or 3 mins to decompress all png files):

```
while ((count = zipInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
         outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

**Edited**: After doing some logging and debugging I found out that the line slowing down so much the execution is : `zipInputStream.read(buffer)` inside the while condition. Any ideas why sometimes it runs extremely fast and some others extremely slow?

Here is my complete method to unzip the downloaded files and save them into android internal storage. I also add the method where the `zipInputStream` is initialized, from the zip file downloaded (both methods executed inside `doInBackground()` ):

```
        private void unZipIntoInternalStorage(ZipInputStream zipInputStream) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Unzipping started ");
        try {
            File iconsDir = context.getDir("icons", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ZipEntry zipEntry;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int count;
            FileOutputStream outputStream;

            while ((zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                File icon = new File(iconsDir, zipEntry.getName());
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(icon);

                while ((count = zipInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                zipInputStream.closeEntry();
                outputStream.close();
            }
            zipInputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG + " Decompress", "unzip error ", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Unzipping completed time required: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
    }

    private ZipInputStream httpDownloadIconsZip(String zipUrl) {

        URLConnection urlConnection;
        try {
            URL finalUrl = new URL(zipUrl);
            urlConnection = finalUrl.openConnection();
            return new ZipInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            return null;
        }
    }
```

To clarify, after testing this method several times and debugging, the blocking for ever always happens in the nested while loop I described previously. But I can't find the reason (see edited clarification)
Also I have already tried this method using `BufferedOutputStream` class and with the same results: nested while loop running forever sometimes and others unzipping successfully in less than a second.

Hope I have been as clear as possible, since I have spent long hours looking for posible causes to the issue in several post regarding unzipping files or java I/O methods with no success.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I believe you are encountering the 'end-of-stream' not found in your inner `while` loop (and you indicated the inner while loop seemed to be causing the problem). As is stands the inner while loop will only exit once it receives the 'end-of-stream' but I have to admit I do not know exactly what the 'end-of-stream' marker is, only that I have experienced similar problems too.

Comment: So how do you solve this issue about not finding the end-of-stream ? Is the any code that can abort the unzipping in case this happens?

Comment: Could you log or print the values of count each iteration? This will give you a clue whether the `read()` method blocks eternally or whether the `write()` method blocks eternally. In case `count == 0` (which should never happen according to the specification of InputStream) interesting problems might occur.

Comment: What kind of `InputStream` is wrapped inside the `ZipInputStream`? Is it a file input stream or an input stream from a socket? In the latter case the network might be a problem. And since the unzipping is executed on a separate thread, are you sure that the `ZipInputStream` is not closed by the thread that actually creates the `AsyncTask` while unzipping is still in progress?

Comment: I edited the post and added the method where the ZipInputStream is created. As you can see is comming from an urlConnnection.getInputStream() which returns  regular InputStream. But both methods httpDownloadIconsZip() and UnzipIntoInternalStorage() are executed in the same thread since they are both called inside doInBackground() from AsynTask().

Comment: Maybe `urlConnection.setReadTimeout(ms);` needed? A 1 KiB buffer is a bit small too.

Comment: I don´t believe the  problem is with the urlConnection since httpDowloadCarrierIConsZip always finishes it´s execution pretty fast leading to the execution of unZipIntoInternalStorage(), which usually runs in less than 1 second ( except for those times where it gets blocked eternally) so I guess its not a problem of the buffer size either.

Comment: I hava tried setting a urlConnection timeout  but the probles still happens. Thanks any way for the suggestion

Comment: @gogognome I did some logging as you suggested and find out that the problem is in the call zipInputStream.read(buffer)  inside the while condition.  Although count is never 0, (because even when the loop "lasts forever" it always finishes decompressing at some point, but instead of taking less than 1 second it takes more than 2 mins to decompress all images). But doing some loging I was able to determine that the call zipInputStream.read(buffer) is tha cause of the decompression loop taking that long. Any ideas why this could happen sometimes?

Comment: The count will never be zero, but you will *block* if you get ahead of the sender. The problem, if any, isn't at this end.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect the InputStream rather than the output to be the issue.

Try :
`return new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream()));`

You can add an argument for setting buffer size, but default settings should be fine for your use case.

The problem is typically caused by small packet size, leading to one read forcing several IO operations.

Ideally, you do want to use also a BufferedOutputStream, since the `read` could read much less than 1kB, but you still do pay a full I/O for each write.

As a general rule, remember I/O is 100 times slower than anything else you could do, and often leads to the scheduler putting your task on Wait. So just use BufferedStream anywhere the stream is not in memory (i.e. always except for StringBufferXXXStream basically).

In your case, due to zip protocol, your `read` could lead to any number of smaller reads on the actual network socket, as Zip parses and interprets headers and contents of the compressed file.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, wrapping the urlConnection.getInputStream() inside BufferedOutputStream as well as wrapping the FileOutputStream inside a BufferedOutputStream, but still having the issue of some execution taking too much time. So could be something related to the network socket? I thought the moment the zipInputStream was returned the network operations where over. Thanks for your suggestion anyway

Comment: I believe the Zip stream will decode entries as it's working (i.e. it's a Stream), not at copnstruction time.

Comment: Since Buffering didn't help, the server you are accessing could be the culprit, maybe giving you low priority when you access a lot of url on it very fast from the same source IP. I think to debug I would separate getting the file contents from the url (in full) from decoding it, e.g. by an intermediate step that copies to a ByteArrayOutputStream before opening the ZipStream. Then time the operations, you could diagnose which files are long to download, and whether your performance issue comes from this download step/network.

Comment: Apparently you are right! looks like the issue is coming from the server. Before we used our web server on Amazon (EC2 instance with nginx server) and recently we’ve migrated to amazon cloudfront to serve static files and since we’ve done this migration this issue has started to happen. Will contact amazon for support. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I know this error. If your zip file has been damaged, when you try to unzip it by `ZipInputStream`, it will be a infinite loop, because the file has no EOF.

But if your unzip it by ZipFile, you can catch that Exception!

```
public static boolean unZipByFilePath(String fileName, String unZipDir) {
    long startUnZipTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        File f = new File(unZipDir);
        if (!f.exists()) {
            f.mkdirs();
        }

        BufferedOutputStream dest = null;
        BufferedInputStream is = null;
        ZipEntry entry;
        ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile(fileName);
        Enumeration e = zipfile.entries();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            entry = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
            is = new BufferedInputStream(zipfile.getInputStream(entry));
            int count = 0;
            byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];

            String destFilePath = unZipDir + "/" + entry.getName();
            File desFile = new File(destFilePath);
            if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                desFile.mkdirs();
            } else if (!desFile.exists()) {
                desFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                desFile.createNewFile();
            }

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFilePath);
            dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER);
            while ((count = is.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                dest.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            dest.flush();
            dest.close();
            is.close();
        }
        zipfile.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "unZipByFilePath failed : " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```